# Cookie is received from an AWS Fargate server behind a load balancer but not set by brower

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, amazon-ecs

I deployed a user login service on AWS ECS fargate behind a AWS load balancer.
I am doing a login network request. i managed to get back the cookie but the cookie is not being set as the cookie tab is empty even after the request.

[image: cookie received]

[image: browser not saving the cookie]

as can be seen the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is `true` and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is the correct origin i am accessing. Also there is a warning sign at the side of `SameSite=None`.

Does anyone knows what might be the problem. Is it more likely a server side problem or frontend problem? I am suspecting this might be because of the AWS ECS or load balancer because it worked fine when I deployed locally.

Comment: you should hover over that warning sign to see what the warning is

Comment: it doesn't give any information when i hover over it

Comment: I can't figure out why Chrome would show that cookie warning icon, but it seems whatever is causing it to show that is the problem. I suggest trying in Firefox to see if it gives you more info.

Comment: Also, it's strange that your request URL is for an IP address if you are using a load balancer. Is that a NLB?

Comment: This is expected behaviour: insecure Web origins (ones whose scheme is `http` and not `https`) are not allowed to set `Secure` cookies. The origin in question (`http://13.250.231.160:8001`) is insecure.

Comment: @MarkB my mistake, my server is not behind a load balancer but my frontend is behind a load balancer. the server is running on an ECS task.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for suggesting to use firefox. I have found the problem, the error it gave me in firefox is `Cookie “token” has been rejected because it is in a cross-site context and its “SameSite” is “Lax” or “Strict”.`
I changed the SameSite attribute to be `none`  in my server and it fixed the problem